# Why index in migration error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('a_delivery_pec_pickup_coef', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index(['location_id', 'weight_limit'], 'location_id_weight_limit_index');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('a_delivery_pec_pickup_coef', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropIndex('location_id_weight_limit_index');
    });
}
```

But when I try the command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

I get the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'location_id_weight_limit_index'; 
>   check that column/key exists

Comment: Have you verified in database this index was really created with this name? Is this possible that you first migrated with different index name (or with default name) and now you try to down the migration?

Comment: how i can chek that index is exists ?

Comment: Go to software you use for managing database (phpmyadmin / heidi sql or something else and verify how exactly your database structure exist). You can also try to change database to empty one, run all the migrations and then rerun `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`. Also keep in mind that maybe what you want is `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` command? This will wipe all the tables for database and run all the migrations but it won't solve the issue if there is something wrong with your index migration.

Comment: Perhaps the Schema class has a method something like hasIndex ()?

Comment: The name of the index seems too long, but I agree with @MarcinNabiałek that you should check if the index exists